# jQuery Click Not Registering

Tags: jquery

So I have a webpage, and upon clicking a link, it performs an xhttp request to change the page, and add a few elements like `Button1`. The xhttp request also adds a jQuery script trying to register the click of `Button1` like so:ctrl k

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert('hi1');
  $( '#Button1' ).click(function() {
    alert('hi2');
  });
)};
```

Neither alert **hi1** or **hi2** show up. I'm guessing that it's something to do with the xhttp request and the document ready not working together

Comment: Are there any errors in console?

Comment: No there isn't any errors

Comment: Where does the script end up being injected in the dom?

Comment: Tried executing the script in the head, as-well as the start of the body, both to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Because **Button1** is added on an xhttp request you need to use event delegation instead of the ready event.

Therefore, you can change your code to:

```
$(document).on('click', '#Button1', function() {
   alert('hi2');
});
```

Comment: Nope, this also didn't display an alert

Comment: As OP has addressed that *Neither alert hi1 or hi2 show up.* issue can't just related to dynamic dom elements its more related to js conflict.

Answer (score 0):

try to replace code with this

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Button1').on('click', function() {
       alert('hi2');
     });
});
```